# TwinStick shooter game controller issue c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity and C#.

I try to make a Top view shooter game using the left and right Thumbstick of my Xbox pad. My character move correctly on the x and z axis with the left Thumbstick. But the rotation of the gun on the y axis with the right Thumbstick is not working correctly, it get stuck in Angles(45°, 135°, 225°, 315°). I can't have a smooth rotation..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

CharacterMotor controller;
public Transform player_turret;
public float deadzone = 0.25f;
private Quaternion desireRotation;

void  Update (){
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*speed*Time.deltaTime, 
                                0, 
                                Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*speed*Time.deltaTime);
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    controller.Move(moveDirection);

    //right stick dead zone
    Vector2 shootDirection = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("FireHorizontal"),     
                                         Input.GetAxis("FireVertical"));
    if(shootDirection.magnitude < deadzone){
        shootDirection = Vector2.zero;
    }else
    {
        Vector3 shootRotation = new Vector3(shootDirection.x, 0, shootDirection.y);
        desireRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(shootRotation);
        player_turret.rotation = desireRotation;
        if((Time.time >= nextFireTime) && Input.GetButton("Button A")){
            FireProjectile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure since I can't test, but is your gun part of your character object? When you rotate your character, the gun will rotate with it without changing the local rotation of the gun. This means if you turn your character a few degrees, and you set the rotation of the gun to 90 degrees, it will be 90 degrees off the character. The gun will be 90+(character.rotation) rotated in the scene.

Comment: hi, the gun object is in an Empty gameObject(player_turret) inside of the character object

Comment: the player_turret object rotate alone, the character isn't

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. If an object turns it's rotation, it rotates based on the parent. Your character's parent is probably nothing, so it'll rotate based on the scene's axes. Your player_turret is a child of the character. Meaning if you rotate your player_turret, it'll do so based on the parents axes. If your parent (character) turns, your player_turret will turn with it because the rotation off the character (parent) will stay the same like this.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Does the player_turret rotate? Does your character not? That's something else than what you said in your original question...

Comment: here is the hierarchy:
>Player>player_turret>gun

Comment: the charater do not rotate, only the player_turret, it's work perfectly when i use OntriggerEnter, locate a enemy, and rotate to him.

Comment: I'm thinking your LookRotation is wrong, or actually the thing you are looking at. `Vector3 shootRotation = new Vector3(shootDirection.x, 0, shootDirection.y);` should perhaps be changed to `Vector3 shootRotation = new Vector3(this.transform.x + shootDirection.x, 0, this.transform.y + shootDirection.y);`

Comment: thank you for your help, but that doesn't solved the issue. I think i found the problem, Input.GetAxis("FireHorizontal") and Input.GetAxis("FireVertical") allways return int values -1, 0 or 1. i thought that it was float values, i have to solve this now

Comment: I Found the Issue and solved it.

Input.GetAxis("FireHorizontal") and Input.GetAxis("FireVertical") was returning int values -1, 0 or 1 and the sensitivity was 1000 on FireHorizontal and FireVertical Inputs, i change them to 1 and It WORKS !

Thank you for your help !

Comment: There we go :) Good find! You should answer your own question to help others who might stumble on the same problem.. Good luck on the rest of your project!